# Log in by pressing enter while password text is in focus

Tags: unity, c#, input

I have a very simple script which is supposed to Check if the return key is pressed while the password text is in focus. 
The issue is that I've tried all 3 methods `Input.GetKeyUp`, `Input.GetKeyDown` and `Input.GetKey` and they all work when the user presses the Return key 2 times at least. I need to be able to log in on one press of the return key. Here is the code I'm using:

```
InputField _input;
bool focused;
public System.Action Callback = () => { };
void Awake()
{
    _input = GetComponent<InputField>();
}

void Update()
{
    focused = _input.isFocused;
    if (focused)
    {
        Debug.Log("Passowrd field is in focus");
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("ENTER KEY PRESSED via getkey");
            Callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the first press of `return` highlight all of the text?

Comment: Yes it does. But the docs of `GetKeyDown` says that it won't recognize unless the user releases the key and presses it again

Comment: The first enter is actually activating the input field, you could just manually activate it when it's in focus. (This might work, but I'm not sure: `if (focused) {_input.ActivateInputField(); Debug.Log("Passowrd field is in focus"); if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return)) { Debug.Log("ENTER KEY PRESSED via getkey"); Callback(); } } else {_input.DeactivateInputField();}`

Comment: Also, my previous comment is not for live use, just for bypassing this problem. It would be pretty unwise to try to deactivate a field every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`InputField.ActivateInputField()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.ActivateInputField.html) is what you are looking for. Here is an example snippet that I wrote for one of my projects:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<string> Entry;

    [SerializeField] private InputField _inputField;

    void Awake()
    {
        _inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener (InputField_OnEditEnd);
    }

    private void InputField_OnEditEnd (string input)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return))
        {
            OnEntry (input);
            _inputField.ActivateInputField();
        }
    }

    private void OnEntry (string entry)
    {
        if (Entry != null)
        {
            Entry.Invoke (entry);
        }
    }
}
```

To understand why this works you need to understand how `EventSystem` handles selection.

Once you press `Return` on an `InputField` while editing, `EventSystem` ends the edit mode but leaves the `InputField` selected. When you press `Return` for the first time after end of the edit mode, the key press is consumed for entering the edit mode again. Then you would need a second `Return` to submit the content.

[`InputField.ActivateInputField()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.ActivateInputField.html) activates the edit mode for you. So when the user presses `Return`, it submits the content instead of being consumed for entering the edit mode.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Nothing happens. I've used your code but tried to print a log inside the `GetKeyDown` condition but nothing happens.

Comment: it's a log-in screen. I want the user to log in by typing in the password and pressing the Return key.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bzPJgTUW

Comment: @NewToUnity No problem! Let's clean this comment section a little bit by removing the back and forth comments.